# How to use html tags inside code block?

Tags: discussion, edits, markdown

I need to use `<del>` html tag inside a block of code, because I have written some code wrong, and someone has answered my question according to my wrong code and now I need to update my question and show that this part of code is wrong and it is updated below. If I use `<del>` inside the code block, it thinks that `<del>` is part of code and only shows `<del>` as part of code. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int <del>mian()</del>
{
cout << "hello world";
}
```

(However, this kind of wrong code may be simply edited and it does not need using `<del>` tag. This is just an example to show my case.)